# conda create: UnsatisfiableError

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am trying to create an environment for an installation (https://github.com/linzhi2013/MitoZ/), but I get the following error. Any suggestions what I need to install/uninstall to make it work?

```
:~$ conda create  -n mitozEnv libgd=2.2.4 python=3.6.0 biopython=1.69 ete3=3.0.0b35 perl-list-moreutils perl-params-validate perl-clone circos=0.69 perl-bioperl blast=2.2.31  hmmer=3.1b2  bwa=0.7.12 samtools=1.3.1 infernal=1.1.1 tbl2asn openjdk
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - biopython=1.69 -> reportlab -> pillow[version='>=2.4.0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.9,<8.7.0a0']
  - blast=2.2.31 -> boost=1.60 -> python=3.5 -> tk[version='>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']
  - ete3=3.0.0b35 -> lxml -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.9,<8.7.0a0']
  - python=3.6.0 -> tk=8.5
```

Comment: Probably the `python=3.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

Take it one step at a time.

1. Why are you specifying a fixlevel 3.6.0 for Python? Unless you have a very good reason, relax this to `python=3.6`. Newer fixlevels might work with different versions of tk, which could resolve some of your problems.
2. blast 2.2.31 drags in a dependency on Python 3.5 via boost 1.60. Relax the version of blast, so you can pull in a version of boost that works with the Python 3.6 you want.

With those changes, try again and see what problems remain.